# Rails 4 - Finding related user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Task: Showing the profile of an employee straight away after his login.

Issue:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @employee = Employee.find_by_email(params[@current_user.email])
  end
end
```

I tried to code in many ways to associate the email of the current user with his respective details from the employees table and the farthest that I could get was it:
[image]
I am sure that I am writing something wrong in this line inside the index thing, but I am researching and all things that I found and tried did not get the employee related to the current user.

Comment: What do your models look like? Use the `annotate` gem first to create db structure comments and then post the code for `User` and `Employee` models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @employee = Employee.where(email: current_user.email).first
  end
end
```

When using Devise, the current user is an instance variable, so you don't need to prefix it with @.

If you are going to have a lot of users, is a good practice to create an index in your database for the email column.

Comment: Thanks a million @DiegoSenott ! It worked!

`Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Employee Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."email" = ?  ORDER BY "employees"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "my_email@site.dn"]]
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (11.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1087ms (Views: 862.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)`

So now I know and thanks for the explanation as well!!! :D

Comment: You´re welcome, glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I like kjmagic13's answer. Use the

```
@current_user.id
```

It pulls all the info associated with the user from the database

Mori's answer is also good.

Comment: If you like another answer, its best to upvote it rather than create a new answer

Comment: @eirikir I cannot upvote because i need +15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL line in your logs corresponds to the `Employee.find_by_email` call:

```
SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

As Mori pointed out, this means you're finding the employee with a `nil` email, which means that `params[@current_user.email]` is `nil`. Since you have no parameters, there's no need to refer to the `params` hash regardless. You should refer just to the `@current_user.email`:

```
Employee.find_by_email @current_user.email
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mori's answer states, you probably didn't intent do use @current_user.email as a hash key into params. I think you're trying to look up the employee record for the current user by email (not by an email submitted as a parameter), like so (also avoiding deprecated find_by_* helpers):

```
@employee = Employee.find_by(email: @current_user.email)
```

I don't think you want to try to do `Employee.find(@current_user.id)` - that's just going to look up the Employee whose id matches the current_user's id - unless Employee and User use the same table that's not going to be meaningful

Answer (score -1):

Why not just find by the ID? `find_by_*` are old.

`@employee = Employee.find(@current_user.id)`

Comment: Because the only one thing that these two tables have to match is the email or does not it matter?

Comment: @Taly this won't work unless `@current_user` is an instance of `Employee`, which would make this code redundant

Comment: Also, `find_by_*` methods actually are not deprecated, but similar methods are: https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders